# Area of Spiric Sections

Tags: geometry

To quote a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287958/solving-intersection-of-translated-spiric-curve) on spiric sections:

> The spiric section is the curve obtained by slicing a torus along a plane parallel to its axis. Assume the torus midplane lies in the $z=0$
> plane, $a$
> is the radius of the torus tube and $c$
> is the distance from the origin of the center of the tube.
> Now cut the torus with the plane $y=r$ and we get the curve: $$z^2=a^2-(c-\sqrt{x^2+r^2})^2$$
> [image]

Is there a result for the *area* of such a spiric section, as a function of the cut location $r$? There's some fairly trivial results for the special points, namely $A(r=c+a)=0$ and $A(r=0)=2\pi a^2$, but between those extremes any closed form solution eludes both me and my middling skill with math software.